# fptd 0.17 and directory access

Tags: c, linux, open-source, ftp

I'm working on FTP demon 1.7 I have following questions.

1. How can I restrict a user to one particular directory? Lets say a user logs in as "admin", he should be having access to only "/tmp" directory, nothing else.
2. I'm going through ftpd's code and trying to modify as per my needs. Any good reference/documents to get hang of current code organization?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question and removing the first point, you can open another question on serverfault for that. The second question is clearly programming related, so its better to split this up instead of simply migrating it.

Comment: Also, from the version number you provided, I'm assuming you are working with NetKit, which contains linux-ftpd-0.17. That was released in July 2000, you might want to start with pureftpd, it could save you some grief.

Comment: I second pure-ftpd. It's really flexible.

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of ftp daemons already capable of your requested feature. I'd suggest you stick to one of those, for example pure-ftpd.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Tim Post and  @speakman

My question lacked the details. I'm using linux-ftpd-0.17 in custom made embedded systems. The only user that exists in the system is "admin" ( with root privileged) and it is required that during ftp session -  the user should only have access to its home directory and not to any other directory.

This customization required changes in ftp daemon code.  The changes were introduced in "cwd" , "pwd" and "retrieve" functions. Please let me know, If you need more information on what changes are made.